StringProperty of type DIR_PATH duplication issue
SOLVED! SEE BOTTOM OF POST
I'm using scripting in Blender to automate some of the work done on my team, and for that I need a path property as a root folder where all the work and exports are saved when a button is clicked. There are a few of these buttons, each does its own action, but for each the same root folder is used.
I figured out how to use a StringProperty for that and it worked great on my machine, but then when a co-worker ran it on her machine, after a few times she ran into a strange bug that happens pretty consistently. She sets a path, does whatever she has to, clicks a button, everything is saved in the root folder, and then by the second or third time she clicks a button, the root folder path is duplicated. So, for example, if it's //Documents/Foo/Bar, it becomes //Documents/Foo/Bar/Documents/Foo/Bar.
Here's my code:
class CustomPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # << cut for brevity >>
    sub_folder: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Sub Folder')
    root_folder: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Root Folder",
        description="Root folder to save files",
        subtype="DIR_PATH",
    }

class UploadModelShelf(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = 'The Label'
    bl_context = 'objectmode'
    bl_category = 'The Category'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        subrow = layout.row(align=True)
        subrow.prop(context.scene.custom_props, 'root_folder')
        # << cut for brevity >>

def get_dir_path():
    full_path = ""
    root_folder = bpy.context.scene.custom_props.root_folder
    if not Utils.is_empty_string(root_folder):
        full_path = root_folder
    else:
        full_path += DOCUMENTS_FOLDER
    full_path = bpy.path.abspath(full_path)
    sub_folder = bpy.context.scene.custom_props.sub_folder
    if not Utils.is_empty_string(sub_folder):
        full_path += f"{sub_folder}/"

    return full_path

# and these are two samples of how I use get_dir_path():
# 1
def create_glb():
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=get_dir_path() + "GLTF.blend")
    # << cut for brevity >>

# 2
class ExportGLBOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'custom.export_glb'
    bl_label = 'Render Op'
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
            filepath=f"{get_dir_path()}export.glb"
        )
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Finished Exporting GLB")

        return {'FINISHED'}

I wasn't able to understand what the cause might be, because it's not reliably reproducible in any specific order of actions. It just happens sometimes once she clicks a second or third button and so on. I'd appreciate any tips or pointers in my search for a solution.
System Info:
Windows 11
Blender 3.6

Thank you all!
SOLUTION:
With the help of @james_t in the comments, I learned that the Blender  Python interpreter behaves a little strange, and the cause of the bug was this line:
       full_path += DOCUMENTS_FOLDER

Even though I was setting it to an empty string with each call and it was supposed to remain an empty string when it reached this line, it didn't actually set it on each call, and ended up chaining the DOCUMENTS_FOLDER over and over again. Changing this line to:
       full_path = DOCUMENTS_FOLDER

solved the issue.

In your statement full_path += DOCUMENTS_FOLDER you are essentially saying full_path = full_path + DOCUMENTS_FOLDER.  Are you sure that this is what you want?

Thank you for your reply! Yes, this piece of code is a bit odd, since I add DOCUMENTS_FOLDER to an empty string, which is exactly the same as full_path = DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, but since I set full_path to an empty string on each call to get_dir_path(), it should always result in just DOCUMENTS_FOLDER for this same condition flow. Just to make sure, I changed this line to say full_path = DOCUMENTS_FOLDER and we'll test it in the next few days. I'll keep you posted.

I also notice that your definition of root_folder: bpy.props.StringProperty(... has no closing paren!  How does blender-python not report that as an error?

Oh, no, sorry, that's my bad. I left it out when I copy-pasted the code here.

Hi @james_t! I sent my colleague the changed script (with full_path = DOCUMENTS_FOLDER) and she's been using it for more than a week now, no sign of the bug! Logically, I can't understand it, because I set full_path to an empty string each time this function is called, and it's always an empty string when it reaches this condition block, but maybe the lesson here is that the code is not interpreted like it normally is in the Python interpreter. You should add your comment as an answer so I can accept it! Thank you so much :)

Agree that it's not obvious to me also.  Sometime with blender I also find that throwing salt over my shoulder solves a problem, or lets loose the devil, LOL.
